# Report for Rest API

Tags: rest, groovy, jmeter

How can I get the total number of passed /failed test cases in JMETER for a rest API. I want the report to be automatically saved in a spreadsheet once I run rest API .

I can pull a report from a csv file for each test case, but I want the total number at a glance instead of counting them for automation purposes like a summary.

Comment: In `View Results Tree` you can write the results to the file. Click on `Configure` what to write and what not.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter has [Summarizer feature](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-2-techniques-get-jmeter-test-results-non-gui-mode) which periodically (by default each 30 seconds as of JMeter 3.2) reports some statistics into console when you [run JMeter test in non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)

[image: JMeter Summarizer Results]

By the end of the test it will print final stats, you can "glance" into it to get the high level test results.